# How to see IP Address behind Log Streams to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently using the Python library `watchtower` to stream JSON log files from a device to CloudWatch.

I now want to use AWS Kinesis Data Firehose to move the logs to Redshift.  I am following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample

I am now setting up a subscription filter to move the logs.  I would like to filter by the IP address the logs are streamed from.  [This article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) discusses implementing filters.  Here is what I found:

`{ $.sourceIPAddress != 123.123.* }`

The only problem is, I don't know how if CloudWatch even stores the source IP Address. Is there some way to query CloudWatch to get the source IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query it if it's part of the log you are sending to the cloudwatch-logs. So if there is a json field "sourceIPAddress" in the log you can use your filter -

```
{ $.sourceIPAddress != 123.123.* }
```

You can check the content of the log in the log-group/log-stream.

Comment: Ahh that answers my question @v_sukt, I wasn't sure if it was built in behind the scenes.  I guess it has to be explicit.  Thanks!